# SQLite vs XML for mobile application

Tags: xml, sqlite, xamarin

In my first xamarin mobile application i need to read data(mostly text). Some 300 Rows with 5column each. I am confused whether to use SQLite or XML.

XML will take up RAM when loading during startup but my application will be faster.

SQLite will be bit slower (but i am not sure if it is will noticeably slow) but it won't take much memory while running.

Finally i was planning to use this database as embedded resources.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct, the question here is to use flat files(XML/JSON) or Sqlite.

Flat files are useful when your applications does a lot more than normal of reading and writing of data. This is due to the fact that, In Sqlite before reading/writing, it is expensive to open and close the db every time. Hence these operations become easier in case of flat files.

In flat files, the whole file needs to be re-written if there is a single minor change.

I would use flat files only when the read/write operations are way off than normal i.e. for extremely fast access.